# How can I call @ConfigProperty as value of @ClientHeaderParam annotation in MicroProfile?

Tags: java, quarkus, microprofile

I would like to set @ClientHeaderParam's value with @ConfigProperty like below;

```
  @ClientHeaderParam(name = "Authorization", value = @ConfigProperty("auth.key"))
```

However it says:

> Incompatible types. Found: 'org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty', required: 'java.lang.String[]'

is there a way to set value with @ConfigProperty like above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default method in your rest-client interface and programatic access to configuration :

```
default String authKey() {
 return ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("auth.key", String.class);
}
```

and in your annotation :

```
@ClientHeaderParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Bearer {authKey}")
```